# Install requests in Rhino Python without terminal

Tags: python, grasshopper

I am trying to install requests so I can use it in the GHPython component in Grasshopper, which runs IronPython, but it does not have a terminal. I have tried manually putting the module files into the lib folder but when I put in requests, there is an error " No module names urllib3" but when I put urllib3 into the folder, the error becomes "unexpected token 'f'". How should I install it or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this has been raised here on mcneel's forum --  https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/getting-requests-module-in-ghpython/147116